# CKEditor - enabling Scayt after launch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

There's an issue with the CKEditor.

If you're having the `config.scayt_autoStartup = true;` statement in your config file and have multiple CKEditors, the page jumps a lot in IE9 and IE10, and scrolls down to a random editor after a specific time. It's insanely annoying for my co-workers.

Now, I would like to have Scayt enabled, but only once the CKEditor has focus. I know how to get to the focus event of the editor, but I don't know how to enable Scayt programmatically at any given point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling SCAYT at startup. Such a shame that solution was needed.

Comment: Im assuming you disabled it at startup and set config.scayt_autoStartup = true;through code to achieve dynamic on and off. is that right ?